# The program crashes after processing SteamAPI_RunCallbacks (). [MinGW C++ and SteamSDK]

Tags: c++, mingw, steam

I am trying to use the results of a call to CCallResult from the Steam library. Took the simplest example from [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api) to find the number of active players SteamUserStats () -> GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers (). A compiled program crashes after a successful call processing. After the crash, I see the result (the number of active players) in a text file.

```
void CGameManager::OnGetNumberOfCurrentPlayers( NumberOfCurrentPlayers_t *pCallback, bool bIOFailure )
{
    if ( bIOFailure || !pCallback->m_bSuccess )
    {
        printf( "NumberOfCurrentPlayers_t failed!\n" );
        return;
    }
    printf( "Number of players currently playing: %ld\n", pCallback->m_cPlayers );

    //СОХРАНИТЬ ДАННЫЕ
    FILE* fsav;
    fsav=fopen("Error.log","w");
    fprintf(fsav,"Number of players currently playing: %ld\n", pCallback->m_cPlayers);
    fclose(fsav);
}
```

I use the MinGw compiler for Windows, and this is most likely a problem. On the Internet I found a couple of people who also faced this problem. I found extremely little information - literally a couple of pages. In general, there were two options: use C Wrapper or use the Visual Studio compiler. I also tried other calls, for example, SteamMatchmaking () -> RequestLobbyList () with the same result. I also tried using "steam_api_flat.h" which in the case of calls did not bring a positive result. But when switching to "steam_api_flat.h", functions returning CSteamID ceased to fly out, for example GetFriendByIndex (int iFriend, int iFriendFlags). What could be the problem? And how to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try running in GDB. Maybe it'll reveal more about the crash.

Comment: @DavidMacek Thanks, maybe I'll try. But most likely I will switch to the Visual Studio C ++ compiler. Steam supports it as the main one on the Windows platform.